# Dynamic start/end dates in bootstrap datepicker according to dropdown Value

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap datepicker to change start/end date in google web app
[my current working datepiker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCVF8.png)
Here's my working code

```
    <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
          <label for="WO_ID" >WO ID</label>
           <select type="number" class="form-control select2" id="WO_ID" name="WO_ID" required>
           <option>1</option>
           <option>2</option>
           <option>OH</option>
             </select>
                </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
        <label for="Progress_Date">Progress Date</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="Progress_Date" name="Progress_Date" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" required>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('.datepicker').datepicker({ 
       format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
       todayHighlight: true,
       autoclose: true,
       startDate: '-5d',
       endDate: '0d'
        });
     </script>
```

I need to change date picker start/end date according to a dropdown("WO_ID") in my web app,

as an example - when dropdown select "OH" i want date range according to following script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({ 
       format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
       todayHighlight: true,
       autoclose: true,
       startDate: '-1m',
       endDate: '0d'
        });
        </script>
```

when dropdown select any other instead "OH" i want date range according to following script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({ 
       format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
       todayHighlight: true,
       autoclose: true,
       startDate: '-5d',
       endDate: '0d'
        });
 </script>
```

I hope youll understand my requirement..
here is link to my [google app script](https://script.google.com/d/1LGyETnazZi6ki5LnylZIqJV4o5QXTFLlUQalFBVQNTRLuNs-6dMQNY4O/edit?usp=sharing) (Refer "Form.html")

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with google apps script

Comment: Yeah, I think so, I linked GAS for further reference.. Thank you for your feed back..